# Dont index files from extension pattern in WebStorm 7.0.2 IDE

Tags: indexing, gruntjs, webstorm

I added an issue on the official tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10127

Is it possible to not indexing some kind of file in webstorm?
Extension: ***.concat.js**, I use Grunt to concat files from directories and generate d.ts.concat.js, lib.concat.js, and I merge all files in one and at the end with grunt uglify I minify the final file.

But when I run the script the IDE froze completely and stop working 75% times.
Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
Put these files in a separate directory and exclude it from the project (right click on dir => Mark directory as => excluded)

Or :
register *.concat.js as a text file (Settings/File Types/Text Files, add *.concat.js to the list of registered patterns)

Comment: ...OR simply add that pattern `*.concat.js` to the **"Ignore files and folders"** field in `Settings | File Types` (affects ALL projects, since this is an IDE-wide setting)